# choppy sound on alsa after 30 min

Tags: c, linux, audio, ubuntu, alsa

I am writing to alsa in 10ms period to play music, it works great at beginning, however, it has some choppy sounds after 30min playing, and the choppy sounds only lasts for a few mins.

Any ideas why?

Environment is: 
Arm cortex-A8
audio codec TLV320AIC3106
linux kernel version: 3.2.0
os: ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS

Comment: There might be something wrong with your code.

Comment: @CL. I compared my alsa write code with mpg123, the only difference is mpg123 set the hw_buffer_size, but I didn't, I use the default buffer size. And some parameters are different, for example: I use very small periods and periods_size.

Comment: Small buffers can lead to problems. Is there any particular reason why you would need generate samples with low latency? If not, use as big a buffer as possible.

Comment: @CL. we want the low latency on the voip call, so we set it as low as possible. The parameters are hardware allowable, which should work properly, isn't it? Because we design our own arm board, is it hardware  problem?

Comment: Playing music is not VoIP. In any case, you have to configure the buffer size so that it is large enough to prevent underruns on your hardware/kernel. (PulseAudio could adjust the latency dynamically.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem.

On PC, we don't need to call snd_pcm_sw_params_set_avail_min, it works great. However, on our arm machine, we have to set it, otherwise, the status of the buffer is unpredictable, which caused choppy sound and background noise. And when you check the status of the playback device, u won't see the underruns, everything is works great except the avail and avail_max values.

Hope this will help someone else. :)